# Access Go's array of arrays from C

Tags: arrays, go, multidimensional-array, cgo

**Clarification:** There does not seem to be a documented example of sending a GO map to a C function as a multidimentional array. This question is intended to find a common solution for anyone sending a collection of data from GO to C.

**Question:**
I have a map[string]string in Go, I'm looking to iterate over this key/value pair in C++.

In GO I have the following to create a multidimensional array

```
    var argv = make([][]*C.char, len(keypairs))
    count := 0
    for key, val := range keypairs {
        var argv2 = make([]*C.char, 2)
        csKey := C.CString(key)
        csVal := C.CString(val)

        argv2[0] = csKey
        argv2[1] = csVal
        argv[count] = argv2
        count++

        C.free(unsafe.Pointer(csKey))
        C.free(unsafe.Pointer(csVal))
    }
    C.writeKeyValuePairs(&argv[0])
```

Then in C++ I have:

```
bool writeKeyValuePairs(char * pairs[][2]) {
     ...
}
```

The result is:
`cannot use _cgo1 (type *[]*_Ctype_char) as type *[2]*_Ctype_char in argument`

---

**Update to @kostix:**
Here's where it's at now:

```
    var argv = make([][2]*C.char, len(tags))
    i := 0
    for key, val := range tags {
        var argv2 = new([2]*C.char)
        argv2[0], argv2[1] = C.CString(key), C.CString(val)
        argv[i] = argv2
        i++
    }
    C.writeKeyValuePairs(&argv[0])
```

The error being:
`Cannot use 'argv2' (type *[2]*C.char) as type [2]*C.char`

Comment: (There's no map; there's a slice of slices; I've updated the title.)

Comment: Thanks @kostix! I had intentionally titled the issue using the naming conventions of each language respectively. The challenge being: A GO *map* to a C *array*

Comment: Can we see the declaration of `writeKeyValuePairs`?

Comment: I just now realized I changed the variable name from "keypairs" to "tags", was not intending to change examples. I'll keep it as the answer you provided also keeps it, and hoping others can follow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Go, `[]T` is not what you think it is:
it is not an array but rather a slice.

A slice is a `struct` of three fields: `length int`, `capacity int` and a pointer to the first element of the underlying (backing) array.

Conversely, in C and C++ a `T[]` is *directly* a pointer to a memory block (iteration over which happens to be done in `sizeof(T)` byte chunks).

Hence your `char *pairs[][2]` is

- a pointer to a memory block of two elements of type `char*[]`,
- where each element is a pointer to another array of unknown number of elements of type `char*`.

…and your Go's `[][]*C.char` is a slice of *slices* (that is `struct`-typed slice headers, not pointers).

You probably need something like this:

```golang
    var argv = make([][2]*C.char, len(keypairs))
    i := 0
    for key, val := range keypairs {
        var argv2 = new([2]*C.char)
        argv2[0], argv2[1] := C.CString(key), C.CString(val)
        argv[i] = argv2
        i++
    }
    C.writeKeyValuePairs(&argv[0])
```

Here we allocate a slice of arrays (of length 2).
You correctly obtain the address of the 1st element of the enclosing array when calling the C side, so having a slice at the top level is just fine.

The problem with this code is that you do not communicate the
length of the data in `argv` to `writeKeyValuePairs` and neither do you use sentinel values at the end of that array, but I hope you've just elided that bit from your example.

I also fail to grasp why you deallocate the memory allocated with `C.CString` right away. The [manual](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/) says:

```golang
// Go string to C string
// The C string is allocated in the C heap using malloc.
// It is the caller's responsibility to arrange for it to be
// freed, such as by calling C.free (be sure to include stdlib.h
// if C.free is needed).
func C.CString(string) *C.char
```

so you appear to deallocate the memory blocks of your key/value pair right after pointers to them were assigned to the corresponding pair of array entries.
I suspect it's a bug: deallocation must take place after the C function finished execution.

---

**Update** as of 26-07-2019:

Here's the working code:

```golang
package main

/*
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    void writeKeyValuePairs(char *v[][2], size_t len) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            printf("i=%i, k=%s, v=%s\n", i, v[i][0], v[i][1]);
        }
        return;
    }
*/
import "C"

import "unsafe"

func main() {
    tags := map[string]string{
        "foo": "42",
        "bar": "12",
    }

    var argv = make([][2]*C.char, len(tags))
    i := 0
    for key, val := range tags {
        var kv [2]*C.char
        kv[0], kv[1] = C.CString(key), C.CString(val)
        argv[i] = kv
        i++
    }

    defer func(items [][2]*C.char) {
        for i := range items {
            k, v := items[i][0], items[i][1]
            C.free(unsafe.Pointer(k))
            C.free(unsafe.Pointer(v))
        }
    }(argv)

    C.writeKeyValuePairs(&argv[0], C.size_t(len(tags)))
}
```

The result:

```sh
$ go build c.go
$ ./c
i=0, k=foo, v=42
i=1, k=bar, v=12
```

Comment: Thanks @kostix!

Still grasping how the allocation works. The example provided has introduced the same problem, slightly. I have updated the question for code formatting since comments don't support it.

Comment: Thank you @kostix! This is a great example of how to move from a Go Map data structure to a C data structure. This could play a major piece of a Go -> C helper package if it were to be built out to to support other data types. Answer accepted.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a map[string]string in Go, I'm looking to iterate over this
>   key/value pair in C++.

---

Using your example,

```
package main

/*
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool writeKeyValuePairs(char *pairs[][2], size_t size) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
        if (fprintf(stdout, "%s: %s\n", pairs[i][0], pairs[i][1]) < 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
*/
import "C"

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "unsafe"
)

func allocCPairs(m map[string]string) (*[2]*C.char, C.size_t) {
    kv := make([][2]*C.char, 0, len(m)+1)
    for k, v := range m {
        kv = append(kv, [2]*C.char{0: C.CString(k), 1: C.CString(v)})
    }
    return &kv[:cap(kv)][0], C.size_t(len(kv))
}

func freeCPairs(cPairs *[2]*C.char, size C.size_t) {
    gPairs := (*[1 << 30][2]*C.char)(unsafe.Pointer(cPairs))[:size]
    for _, pair := range gPairs {
        for _, p := range pair {
            C.free(unsafe.Pointer(p))
        }
    }
}

func writeKeyValuePairs(m map[string]string) error {
    cPairs, size := allocCPairs(m)
    defer freeCPairs(cPairs, size)

    rv := C.writeKeyValuePairs(cPairs, size)
    if !rv {
        return fmt.Errorf("writeKeyValuePairs: write error")
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    m := map[string]string{
        "K1": "V1",
        "K2": "V2",
        // ...
        "Kn": "Vn",
    }
    fmt.Println(m)

    err := writeKeyValuePairs(m)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
        return
    }
}
```

Output:

```
map[K1:V1 K2:V2 Kn:Vn]
K1: V1
K2: V2
Kn: Vn
```